# Remove RSS feed from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site and found a theme that I like, the only problem is that at the bottom of all pages I find an RSS feed button that I cannot seem to be able to remove. [image: See image below] Do you have any idea how to do it and if possible append the contact page instead? I really dont need the RSS idk why themes seem to be pushing it so hard. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check in footer.php, it's probably in there.

Comment: it's within the theme files like footer.php in your theme folder. or just find the class it uses and add custom css in customiser with `display:none;`

Answer (score 0):

see this 
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/

there are and other plugins:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-feeds/

or add this to function.php
/**
 * disable feed
 */

```
function fb_disable_feed() {
    wp_die( __('No feed available, please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!') );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```

from
https://www.wprssaggregator.com/rss-tricks-clean-way-get-rid-rss-feed/